# How can I restrict filenames to only allow [A-Za-z0-9_-.] in Windows?

Tags: windows, filenames

For *reasons*, I want to limit filename characters to the set `[A-Za-z0-9_-.]` (upper & lowercase alphabet, numerals 0 to 9, underscore, hyphen, and period).  No spaces, exclamation points, @ signs, etc.

I know Windows prevents `\ / : * ? " < > |`

I was hoping this info was stored in a Registry key, but 30 minutes of searching didn't turn up anything useful.  Even tried searching for the ASCII values of those chars; no joy.

Anyone know a way to do this?

BTW, I just realized how much faster it is to export the registry to a file and use a good editor (Notepad++ for instance) to search.  WTF is regedit so slow??

ETA: to clarify, I only want to limit characters in filenames in the "File save...", "File save as.." and Windows Explorer's "Rename" functions.  Doesn't have to be "any filename created by every installed app".

Comment: Impossible - if you ever got such a restriction working, Windows will probably just die. What's your real problem?

Comment: Agreed, this will destroy the OS as you know it. Theoretically it could be done at a file system driver level, but you are assuming every application on the computer will be aware of and have error control for such a wonky condition... Are you trying to do this for a specific directory used by a specific process?

Comment: Though Windows does not provide an option to *prevent* filenames with problematic characters, you could have a batch-script to automatically rename files after-the fact. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636996/replace-or-delete-certain-characters-from-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder, and tools such as Bulk Rename Utrility, https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/ .

Comment: Is this for all existing filename characters or all new ones moving forward? FYI, you can't get rid of the dot that comes before a filename extension either way.

Comment: For example, it wouldn't be full proof but you could use autohotkey to listen out for when explorer.exe is the active application and have the script automatically block certain characters from being typed. You can also bind the script to activate when F2 (rename shortcut) is pressed. But depends if that sort of half way solution is suitable for your workflow?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks for that.  I do something similar using an old renaming program ("1-4a Rename"), but I like the idea of something that happens automatically.  I'll try working with your suggestion.

And windows does indeed prevent certain characters... try renaming a file with a space or a colon.  I just want to add to the already-existing list of verboten characters.